# How to create polygon from xy data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, polyline-creation

I have huge number of x and y data . these are left longitude,right longitude,buttom latitude and up latitude. each row is an extent of a polygon.i'd like to create a polygon using these data without programming in ArcGIS. is there any tool to create polygon automatically?
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ET Geowizards Generate (Import from Text) and use a **Box** type.

If new to this free (some tools only) ArcGIS addon, go to http://www.ian-ko.com.

For this you need to do a some simple formatting of your excel to be

id,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax  - formatting is explained in the tool help.