# How to create polygons from box type coordinates using ET GeoWizards?

Tags: extents, polygon-creation, spatial-etl, et-geowizards

I have a [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K3Bp9ujOY81_MWZjbQX43aaeCbwRKO5TZGGb3HCyKWE/edit?usp=sharing) that has an ID and coordinates for *Left*, *Right*, *Top*, *Bottom* and I would like to create rectangles out of those coordinates. This rectangles should have around 4 km per side.

[image: Exampe image]

Using [ET GeoWizards](https://www.ian-ko.com/Downloads.html) standalone version with the tool [*Import/Export*](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42935/55216) > *Generate(Import from text)* > select *Box* from *Import geometry type* it should be possible to do the exact thing I need, the only issue is that my rectangles are just way to big, regardless of what combinations of *xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax.* All the rectangles should be within the borders of Kenya and not covering half of Africa.

[image: how my polygons look]

I am quite sure that I am doing something wrong with that tool, but just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Qgis to create squares, then use the Buffer tool under the vector menu ---> "Geoprocessing tools".

[image]